# How do I update the database from a checked radio button?

Tags: android

```
package com.example.admin.userregistrationsample;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Some extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{
   private EditText branch;
   public TextView list,list2;
   Button bt, bt1;
   String temp1;
   String text1,temp, usn,text;
   String res;
   String[] parts;
   int count;
   RadioGroup rg;
   RadioButton[] rb;
   GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
   LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
   private static final String JSON_URL = "http://192.168.43.144/mini1/subject.php";
   private static final String SUB_URL = "http://192.168.43.144/mini1/store.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_some);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    usn = getIntent().getStringExtra("USN");
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
    bt.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(this);
    branch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
    //invokeLogin();
}

   //@Override
    public void onClick(View v)
   {

    if (v == bt)
    {
        invokeLogin();
    }
    if (v == bt1)
    {
        register(temp,usn);
    }
   } 

    public void invokeLogin()
    {
       text = branch.getText().toString();
       getJSON(text);
     }
    public  void getJSON(String text)
    {
      final String urlSuffix = "?branch=" + text;
      gj.execute(urlSuffix);
    }

    public class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;

       public GetJSON()
       {

       }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(Some.this, "Please Wait...", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String uri = params[0];

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(JSON_URL + uri);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String json;
                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(json).append("\n");
                }

                return sb.toString().trim();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String s)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            res=s.replaceAll("\"", "");
            res = res.replaceAll(",","\n ").replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ');
            parts = res.split("\n");
            count=parts.length;
            mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear2);
            rb = new RadioButton[count];
            rg = new RadioGroup(getBaseContext());
            rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                rb[i] = new RadioButton(getBaseContext());
                rb[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                rb[i].setTextSize(25);
                rg.addView(rb[i]);
                rb[i].setText(parts[i]);
            }

            mLinearLayout.addView(rg);
            rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(i);

                        if (btn.getId() == checkedId) {

                            temp1 = (String) btn.getText();
                            list2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.select);
                            list2.setText(temp);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}

      public void register(String sub  ,String usn)
      {
         String urlSuffix = "?subject=" + sub + "&usn=" +usn;
         class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

          ProgressDialog loading;


        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(Some.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            if (s.equals("successfully registered")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String s = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(SUB_URL + s);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String result;
                result = bufferedReader.readLine();

                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
      }

      RegisterUser ru=new RegisterUser();
      ru.execute(urlSuffix);
     }
 }
```

I have retreived the checked radio button value to variable temp. And it is appearing in the `TextView` but when I pass that value to register function it is not taking the value how to do that? Please anyone help..!

Comment: Amrutha first thing is your code structure is not proper. you create asynck object publicly you should create it when you need it.  Reason behind that is when your class call that time it take memory because you create on public. so its not good way becuase if user just open that class and not click on button on which you perform  task still its takes memory because you create it public. so you should create object  on click.so it allocate memory when user click on button.

Comment: temp1 = (String) btn.getText();where did the variable temp get its value?

Comment: second thing is you did not return string from getjson doinbackground() method. and you want to get result from postExecute();

Comment: where is your database code?

Comment: use "setOnCheckedChangeListener" out side the async class. Because you are performing operation of getting value from text view and after completion of async class all variables related to it become null.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code for use **setOnCheckedChangeListener** outside the async class.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(!result.equals("null"){
        ((your activity name) activity).parseJsonResponse(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

and add below method in your activity.

```
public void parseJsonResponse(String result) {
    //use setOnCheckedChangeListener here.
}
```

Comment: i hav tried above method by writting setonCheckedChangeListener outside asyn but i didnt get..

Comment: use outside from the async but inside to parseJsonResponse. Because when you will use to change Listener inside the parseJsonResponse then values wil not find as null.